# Merge 2 associative arrays in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have 2 arrays, so first is:

```
{
    "title_heading_1": "Name",
    "last_name": "Trenkle",
    "first_name": "Jason",
    "middle_name": "Jason",
}
```

And the second one is:

```
{
    "Title Heading 1": "",
    "Last Name": "",
    "First Name": "",
    "Middle Name": "",
}
```

The question is how am i going to merge those 2 arrays where the key of the first array will be replaced by the key of the second array. So the result will be like this:

```
{
    "Title Heading 1": "Name",
    "Last Name": "Trenkle",
    "First Name": "Jason",
    "Middle Name": "Jason",
}
```

How would i do that on PHP. I tried foreach but still didn't get the right output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the keys and values match and are guaranteed to be in order, you can very easily do:

```
$result = array_combine(array_keys($second), array_values($first));
//array_values is probably not necessary
```

If the keys of the first and/or second array could be in any order but are consistently named as above, this should do the trick:

```
foreach ($first as $key => $value) {
   $second[ucwords(str_replace('_', ' ', $key))] = $value;
}
```

Oh and use `json_decode` to decode the strings into PHP arrays if you don't already know to do this.

Answer (score -2):

```
$array1 = (array) json_decode('{
    "title_heading_1": "Name",
    "last_name": "Trenkle",
    "first_name": "Jason",
    "middle_name": "Jason",
}');

$array2 = (array) json_decode('{
    "Title Heading 1": "",
    "Last Name": "",
    "First Name": "",
    "Middle Name": "",
}');

$result = array_merge($array1, $array2);
print_r($result);
```

Comment: Each array has different keys.  `array_merge` won't get the desired results here.

Answer (score -2):

Use [array_combine](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php). First parameter is for the keys, the second is for the values. e.g.

```
<?php
$a = array('green', 'red', 'yellow');
$b = array('avocado', 'apple', 'banana');
$c = array_combine($a, $b);

print_r($c);
?>
```